# What's the best/fastest way to recognize if a string number is exactly representable in floating point (or double)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determine whether a given string that represents a decimal number is exactly representable as a double. I'd be particularly keen on a javascript solution, but anything is fine (I can port).

I could `parseFloat`, stringify, then see if that string matches the input string, but I'm wondering if there's a better/faster way to do this. I imagine someone with in depth knowledge of the IEEE floating point standards would have a better way to do this, but that person isn't me.

Comment: Do you have any specific examples where your approach above wouldn't work? It's true that the standard mechanisms of converting numbers to strings gloss over some imprecision... (This is regardless of the scientific notation /  non-scientific-notation issue.)

Comment: parseFloat("Infinity") = "Infinity"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not saying the method I described wouldn't *work*, I'm just hoping for a method that's a little more in tune with the actual IEEE spec. The method I described is pretty brute force.

Comment: @soft87 No... `parseFloat("Infinity") === Infinity`. But if you're point was my method doesn't work in that case, good point, but not really relevant to my question since I'm asking about decimal numbers represented as stringe, not things that javascript considers numbers.

Comment: const isFloat = n => !!(n%1)

Comment: you could probably use the `toFixed` method, which takes a precision range up to 20 : `parseFloat("0.4").toFixed(20) === "0.40000000000000002220"`

Comment: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js

Comment: @BT: Well, you do have to be careful. `0.1` is not exactly representable, but `parseFloat("0.1").toString() == "0.1"` is true, because as I vaguely mentioned in the comment above, the standard rules for outputting a string for an IEEE 754 binary floating point number are to only output as many digits as are required to reliably distinguish it from the adjacent representable value.

Answer (score 5):

Any number which has a fractional part that does not end with `5` is not exactly representable as a binary floating point number.

A representable number has a fractional part which is a sum of `1/(2^N)`. Any such sum ends with the digit `5`.

This does not mean a number with `5` in the end is always representable, to refine this we would have to check if the fractional part is indeed such a sum.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that mean that `parseFloat("1.1")` should return something other than `1.1`?

Comment: If it prints `1.1` there is some rounding. `1.1` is not exactly representable.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. I'm surprised its rounding by default there. Certainly there's  more to it tho. I'm pretty sure there are large numbers below a double's maximum that can't be exactly represented either, and similarly on the low end. I'm hoping for a more general procedure.

Comment: Yes, this is just a general and theoretical hint. To know if a number not ruled out by this is exactly representable as a specific floating point type is much more complicated I guess :)

Comment: Gotcha. Would you recommend that I just implement my brute force method I touched on in my OP? Using `printf("%20.20f", number)` like you did in that live example would help. Maybe it'd be better to convert both to binary and compare bits?

Comment: I would also try the parse - print - compare approach, I think it should be possible if you can disable rounding. But I know no JavaScript unfortunately.

Comment: I think it's any number that doesn't end with `.5`  eg. `1.5` is ok, but `1.05` is not.

Comment: @Keith I just edited the answer to be more precise - yes `0.05` is not representable, but for example `1/8 + 1/16 = 0.1875` is.